# asp.net mv 5, DropDownListFor with ViewModel not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC 5 site, I would like to use a strongly typed DropDownListFor with a ViewModel - not with ViewBag.

I have found various articles on this - but they all seem to have huge holes - for example this one doesnt cover editing, and I do not understand how or when "SelectedFlavourId" should be used.
http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/11/dropdownlistfor-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx

I have several requirements.

- When editing the story I would like a drop down list of all places to
  be displayed - with the associated place (if any) - selected.
- I want to use the strongly typed DropDownListFOR (as opposed to 
  DropDownList).
- I would like to use a ViewModel not the ViewBag.
- I want to add a "No Associated Place" which will be
  selected if PlaceId is null.
- I want to add a css class = "form-control" to the DropDownListFor.

The below is as far as I have got after a day of frustration.

A story can be optionally associated with a PlaceId. A blank placeId is also valid. A place can also be associated with more than one story.

**Models**

```
public class Place
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string PlaceName { get; set; }
}   

public class Story
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? PlaceId { get; set; }
    public string StoryName { get; set; }
}

public class StoryPlaceDropdown
{
    public Story story { get; set; }
    public Guid SelectedStoryId;
    public IEnumerable<Place> places;
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> placeItems
    {
        get
        {
            return new SelectList(places, "Id", "PlaceName");
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Edit(Guid Id)
{
    var spd = new StoryPlaceDropdown();

    spd.places = PlaceRepo.SelectAll();
    spd.story = StoryRepo.SelectStory(Id);
    spd.selectedStoryID = apd.story.Id;

    // Return view
    return View(spd);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(StoryPlaceDropdown spd)
{
    // Never gets this far
    spd.Places = PlaceRepo.SelectAll();

    return View();
}
```

**In View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedStoryId, Model.PlaceItems)
```

This populates the DropDownList fine. However it does not select the correct item in edit view. Also when I submit the form I get this error: 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. on this line in the view @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedStoryId, Model.PlaceItems)

How can I get this all working? Thanks.

Comment: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedStoryId, Model.PlaceItems, "No Associated Place", new { @class = "form-control" })` to address the last 2 dot points (the 3rd parameters add a `null` label option, and the 4th adds the class name). If the value of `SelectedStoryId` matches exactly one of the `Place.Id` values, then that option will be selected.

Comment: As for the `NullReferenceException`, you need to show the code in your POST method (I assume you must be trying to access a value in property `placeItems` which will be `null`) and have not repopulated the `SelectList` when you return the view.

Comment: In addition you model contains a field for `SelectedStoryId` - it needs to be a property - `public Guid SelectedStoryId { get; set;}` in order to bind

Comment: thanks - this set me on the right path on a couple of points - turned out I had forgotten the { get; set; } accessors on model properties which was the main issue though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this - I had stupidly forgotten the { get; set; } accessors on the ViewModel, doh!

Answer (score -1):

You can resolved this by these three steps:

Step 1:Create viewmodel

```
 public class StoryPlaceDropdown
 {
  Required]
  [Display(Name = "SelectedStory")]
  public int SelectedStoryId { get; set; }
 }
```

Step 2:After this on controller you can write:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Guid Id)
{
 var spd = new StoryPlaceDropdown();
  ViewBag.PlaceItems= PlaceRepo.SelectAll();
 spd.story = StoryRepo.SelectStory(Id);
 spd.selectedStoryID = apd.story.Id;
 return View(spd);
}
```

Step 3: And on view you can write

```
 <div class="col-sm-6">
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedStoryId, new SelectList(@ViewBag.PlaceItems, "Id", "PlaceName"), "---Select---", new { @class = "form-control select-sm" })
            </div>
```